# Add css to masterpage (SharePoint Online/Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, master-page, css, cssregistration

I have a css to hide list search box on document libraries. It's in the SiteAssets library.

I can edit a document library view and add Content Editor webpart and add css reference and able to hide.

However, I added following code to masterterpage after `core.css` but it doesn't fire. Any idea why?

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/hideSearchBox.css%>" runat="server"  After="corev15.css" />

The css is 

<style>
.ms-inlinesearch-divbaseline{ display: none !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: if your css is in an external file, why do you have the style tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable publishing features on the site collection (SP_Site) and on the web (SP_Web) and set the alternate CSS URL to your css-file.

> 1. Find "Site Collection Features" setting and enable all features with name "publishing" in it.
> 2. Find "Manage Site Features" setting and enable all feature with name "publishing" in it.
> 3. Find "Master Page" setting link under "Look and Feel".
> 4. Click "Alternate CSS URL". This is where you apply your own CSS file.
> 5. Upload a CSS file to any document library. Ideally to "Style Library".
> 6. Go to step 4 and choose your uploaded CSS file.

Source: [Most upvoted answer to the question "CSS and master page - Sharepoint online - Office 365"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/129593/6382)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add in the HTML page (ex: seattle.html) then use the below code

```
<!--MS:
<style type="text/css">-->
  .ms-inlinesearch-divbaseline{ display: none !important;}
<!--ME: </style>-->
```