# Hide link in suitelinkbar

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can someone help me out with a css code? We have a suitelinkbar with a couple of options (Webmail,Colleages,social,mydocuments.)

I would like to hide the link "Webmail". The other links has to be visible.

On the forum i found some css, but thats for removing the whole Suitelinkbar.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

This is the suitebar im writing about.

[image]

With F12 in browser. This is the info i get from I.E.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you update with screenshot and its HTML elements?

Comment: Hi Anil, I updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: can you expand the "li" tag and then a new screenshot?

Comment: Hi user3328306, i updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still hard to tell based on last screenshot.
try:

```
<style>
#suiteLinksBox ul:first-of-type li:first-of-type {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

or terrible css

```
<style>
#ct100_ct151_ct103_Outlook:first-of-type { display:none; }
</style>
```

Comment: I will hide "Collega's" I guess. You need the <LI> above this one. and then get the Id of it.

Comment: Hi User3328306, Yes, the above code removes "Collega's. when i look at the <LI> above, i see the same Id. See screenshot.

Comment: edited, retry above code, it should hide the first item.

Comment: Yes sir! Trying now!

Comment: Hi MP, I added the code. The webmail disappeared!! but "#sociaal" also disappeared. If #Sociaal can be visible again that would be perfect!

Comment: aha, nice, mooi, i updated again the code :) please try

Comment: Nee, helaas MP. this time nothing changes. All options stay available.

Comment: again an update, this should really work based on the above screenshot...

Comment: Hi MP, your code works! i just have to wait 1 minutes and #sociaal came back! :). Can you help me with one last question? How can i add this code to all pages? Now its only working on the home page. (i added the code through content editor).

Comment: nice :D you could alternate CSS of master page check this thread how to do it: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148029/add-css-to-masterpage-sharepoint-online-office-365

Comment: Harstikke bedankt MP :). i'll check the Thread!!

Answer (score 0):

Updating **M.P.'s** answer,

Try this,

```
<style>
#suiteLinksBox ul:first li:first {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Anil, No difference. Alle options still available.

Comment: no that is a jquery extenstion.